# Code to send the contents of a text file into a terminal window

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, password, paste

I'm looking for some code to be able to send the contents of a text file to the terminal window at the press of a button or through by typing an alias into the terminal.  If I explain what I'm trying to do it will be clearer.

I use an ubuntu machine to manage some equipment, currently I have it setup so that when I type an alias (for example equipment1) it auto SSH's into equipment1.  It also sends a password which allows me to login without having to type it.  The problem is this equipment requires a second password to enter a high privileged level.  After it logs in using the first password it displays an OK button with text showing the second password that I have to copy and paste into the terminal to get into the higher level.

I'm after some code that will auto read the contents of a text file containing some code and the second password and auto send it to the terminal window so I don't have to cut and paste it in from the button text.  I don't mind if it executes when I click an OK button but I want it to run the code to login to the equipment without displaying it to the screen.

What makes it difficult is that once I login to the equipment the first time I don't have access to the terminal code as I'm SSHed into the equipment so it has to be able to run all at once from the alias.

Hopefully this is enough information for someone to understand what I'm trying to do and help me out.

All help is very much appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

**Storing passwords is generally wrong**. Logging in through `ssh` storing the user's password in `~/.bashrc` (and / or in the commands' history) is not safe for obvious reasons; one might use `ssh` keys instead, as suggested in the comments by lemonslice.

However if this is the path you want to follow, just pipe the password to the `ssh` command; using `echo` with the `-e` option will escape escape sequences such as `\n` allowing you to fake the <kbd>Return</kbd> key hit and to even go through multiple prompts:

```
echo -ne 'password\n' | ssh user@host
```

```
user@debian ~ % echo -ne 'password1\n' | ssh user@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@localhost's password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
zsh: command not found: password1
user@debian ~ % echo -ne 'password1\npassword2\npassword3\n' | ssh user@localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@localhost's password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
zsh: command not found: password1
zsh: command not found: password2
zsh: command not found: password3
```

Comment: You might want to use ssh keys for authenticatation to avoid the need to store passwords this way (if your equipment supports them).

Comment: @lemonslice Did you want to write this under the question? As this isn't really different from what OP is already doing; if he's `ssh`ing passing the password with the command, as it looks like he's doing, the second password will be stored in the commands' history no more than how the user's password it's being stored as of now; on the other hand I agree that this is something OP should be warned about, so I added it to the answer.